# CakePHP 2.x how to manage multiple user-tables and access areas?

Tags: cakephp

i'm planning a new project with cakephp and i have a problem.

i want to create multiple access areas and multiple user-tables i.e. like a shop system:

1. group: customers
2. group: merchants
3. group: affiliate-partners
   (4. group: admins [this maybe with acl])

every group will have its own area (domain.tld, domain.tld/merchants, domain.tld/affiliate)
(i know about prefex-routing, but will it works with my idea?)

How can i manage 3 separate logins, if i.e. a merchant logged in, he wouldn't automatically logged in in affiliate area? in my first trys i see, that there's only one cookie and every merchant would be logged in in other areas too without having an account there.

please help me and point me in the right direction ;)

(sry for my terrible english)
greetings from germany

m.

Comment: I think adding all the sections as plugins, each with their own Auth rules/table should get close to what you're looking for.

Comment: but how do i check for the right login, when $this->Auth->user() is always true, when i login in one area and browse to another area, where $this->Auth->user() is true then too?

Answer (score 0):

You can do some processing after logging in:

```
if($this->Auth->login()) { 
    $role = $this->Auth->user('role'); // your users must have a `role` field. 
    if($role=='affiliate') { 
        $this->redirect('/affiliates'); 
    }
    // ...
```

There are better ways of doing it; but depends on your exact requirements. This is quite simple and not very robust though.

Comment: how can i set and check allowed actions with that way? $this->Auth->allow() wont work, or am i wrong, because $this->Auth->user() is always true?

Comment: from your OP it wasn't clear if you wanted to completely deny access to the other areas depending on the user group, or just redirect when they login. ACL would be the correct way to go. The manual has a [good example](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html) which you could probably work with